# How to select and order an EmbeddedID in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one table with a composite primary key:

```
public class IdmTenantBoard implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private IdmTenantBoardPK id;

@Column(name="board_display_name")
private String boardDisplayName;

@Column(name="board_name")
private String boardName;
```

The embedded class looks like this:

```
public class IdmTenantBoardPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="board_id")
private int boardId;

@Column(name="tenant_id")
private String tenantId;
```

The method I am using to call query is as follows:

```
public String getMaxBoardId(){
      TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("select o from IdmTenantBoard o order by o.IdmTenantBoardPK.boardId desc",String.class);
      query.setMaxResults(1);
      List<String> lResults = query.getResultList();
      String maxBoardId=null;
      if((null!=lResults)&&(!lResults.isEmpty())){
          maxBoardId=lResults.get(0);
      }
      return maxBoardId;
}
```

What do I need to get the `boardId` sorted in Descending order? I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: IdmTenantBoardPK of: com.newrubric.idm.common.entities.IdmTenantBoard [select o from com.newrubric.idm.common.entities.IdmTenantBoard o order by o.IdmTenantBoardPK.boardId desc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In following `IdmTenantBoardPK` is type of the embedded id and name of the property is `id`:

```
@EmbeddedId
private IdmTenantBoardPK id;
```

That's why `o.IdmTenantBoardPK.boardId` cannot be used in queries. Instead of it `o.id.boardId` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'id' is property name, so use `o.id.boardId` instead of `o.IdmTenantBoardPK.boardId`.

Answer (score 0):

Using '.' operator we can specify sorting functionality on embeddedId fields.

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NAME")
    private String projectName;

    @Column(name = "ORGANIZATION")
    private String organization;

    ......
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectId projectId;

    @Column(name = "STARTED_TIME")
    private Timestamp startedTime;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private String active;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    ......
    ......
}
```

As you see above snippet ProjectId is a composite key for the  entity Project. I can specify sorting on organization field like below.

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC, Arrays.asList("projectId.organization"));
```

Demo Application [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/03/spring-boot-jpa-sort-by-embeddedid-field.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try this, it works like a charm.

Add this to your actual code

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"projectId.organization");
```

Add this method to the Repository

```
List<AccessoriesFile> findByorganization(String organization, Sort sort);
```